# Evaluating the joint density of U=X and V=X+Y where X and Y are U~(0,1)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I'm trying to solve a joint distribution problem with $X$ and $Y$ being distributed uniformly on $[0,1.]$ Then, $U=X$ and $V=X+Y$.

I know that $f_{(U,V)}(u,v)= \text{Jacobian} \cdot f_X(u)\cdot f_Y(v-u)$

My question is how to evaluate $f_Y(v-u)$. For a normal, exponential, poisson distribution the intuition on where to plug in is clear. I'm guessing for the uniform, it doesn't matter what value is plugged into $f_Y$, because the pdf is flat?

EDIT: I've figured out the domain of the joint distribution, being $0{\leq}u{\leq}v{\leq}u+1{\leq}2$

This gives rise to a parallelogram on $(U,V)$ bounded by $0{\leq}v{\leq}2$ and $0{\leq}u{\leq}1$, and more specifically bounded by lines $v{\leq}u+1$ and $u{\leq}v$.

I worked out the Jacobian to be 1.

But still, for evaluating $f_Y(v-u)$ and $f_X(u)$, I don't see the connection. I know that in the end,  $f_{(U,V)}(u,v)= 1$ on the domain I defined above, but still not quite sure how to get there.

Comment: It does matter, but only as to whether $v-u \in [0,1]$ or not. So the support of $(U,V)$ is a parallelogram.

Comment: You should be careful about the distinction between $X$ and $x$ and between $Y$ and $y$ and between $U$ and $u$. I did some correction in the question.

Comment: One does not "solve" $f_Y(v-u);$ one might _evaluate_ $f_Y(v-u).$ One solves problems; one solves equations; one _evaluates_ expressions.

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. I can see the area bounded on $(U,V)$ is bounded by $0<u<1$ and $0<v<2$, still not sure how to carve the parallelogram out of the given information. Should I plug in the $X+Y$ and $X$ into the bounds?

Comment: Or rather, for the bounds $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$, plug in $x=u$ and $y=v-u$ to get the parallelogram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the problem statement, it seems that the independence of $X$ and $Y$ is assumed. Therefore, the joint density $f_{(X,Y)}$ of $(X,Y)$ is the product of the marginal densities $f_{X}$ and $f_{Y}$, i.e.
\begin{aligned}
f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) &= f_{X}(x)\, f_{Y}(y) \\
&= \boldsymbol{1}_{[0,1]}(x) \, \boldsymbol{1}_{[0,1]}(y) \, .
\end{aligned}
The random variable $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed over the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.
Since the Jacobian of the transformation $(X,Y) \mapsto (X,X+Y)$ is equal to one, the change of variable formula writes
\begin{aligned}
f_{(U,V)}(u,v) &= f_{(X,Y)}(u,v-u)\\
&= \boldsymbol{1}_{[0,1]}(u) \, \boldsymbol{1}_{[0,1]}(v-u) \, .
\end{aligned}
The random variable $(U,V)$ is uniformly distributed over a parallelogram $(\mathcal {P})$, defined by
$$
(\mathcal{P}):\qquad 0\leq u\leq 1 \quad\text{and} \quad u\leq v \leq 1+u \, .
$$

Comment: my question is how to evaluate $\boldsymbol{1}_{[0,1]}(u)$ or $\boldsymbol{1}_{[0,1]}(v-u) $ I know they end up being 1, but what's the reasoning?

Comment: @pajkatt Indicator functions are such that $\boldsymbol{1}_{[0,1]}(x) $ is one if $0\leq x\leq 1$, zero otherwise. Similarly, $f_{(U,V)}(u,v)$ is one if $(u,v)$ belongs to a parallelogram, zero otherwise. Note that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\, dx\, dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f_{(U,V)}(u,v)\, du\, dv = 1\, , $$ i.e. the surface area of that parallelogram is one.